# iOS native app wrapper for push notifications in PWA

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to create a native iOS app which only services as a wrapper for a pwa?

So the native app has no functionality other then to load the pwa inside of it and some background functions like push notifications.

This way I would like to create the functionality of push notifications, but still only have to create a pwa.

So when you open the native app this app will open the pwa (In my mind it looks similar to an iframe inside the native app). Everything will happen in the pwa, but we can still send push notification and use other features which are not yet available in the pwa.

If this is possible how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Apple will not approve your app

Answer (score 1):

Apple writes:

> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn’t provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, it may not be accepted.
>   [Link here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design)

I've heard that they are very consistent in not allowing apps outside of their guidelines and as long as you are not giving additional value in the app, that is not present on the website (your PWA), it will not be accepted.

I still have not heard anyone who succeeded with the wrapping alone, but if there are cases I am very interested to know too.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple will not approve your app

Comment: Apple has gotten more aggressive in rejecting hybrid apps. You have to be 'app-like' enough, section 4.2.6 in their documentation.
They have also added language about doing what you are doing, just wrapping a website in a shell wont work these days.
Also you can fall back to SMS on iOS for messaging, that is what I do.